# zero downtime deployment for frontend resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-cloudfront

My stack is Wildfly, angular, spring, RDS, cloudfront. Frontend resources (html/js etc) are stored in app (ie delivered by Wildfly).

For backend and DB I can deploy with zero downtime with 2 EC2 behind ELB, but I am not sure how to handle this scenario:

- User get old js/html from our server -> deployment of new version done -> user click on something which use old api (eg, the new version has a new mandatory param)

Is there a way to avoid this? I can only think of putting default value for the new param. Or would API versioning make sense here?

Another question: what if the frontend resources are delivered by cloudfront + s3? how to make the deployment of new resources to s3 in sync with backend?

Answer (score 2):

> I can only think of putting default value for the new param. Or would
>   API versioning make sense here?

This sounds like exactly what API versioning is intended to solve. You would change API versions anytime there is a change that would break clients of the previous version.

> Another question: what if the frontend resources are delivered by
>   cloudfront + s3? how to make the deployment of new resources to s3 in
>   sync with backend?

Deploying them at the same time is up to you. That's part of your deployment process that you need to automate somehow. You can use versioning and order of deployment to help some here. For example, if your entire front-end is deployed on S3:

1. Deploy a new version of your API, under a new API version number
2. Deploy new static UI resources
3. Issue a CloudFront cache invalidation
4. Users start seeing new front-end resources that reference the new back-end API version

If your front-end UI is a mix of EC2 server dynamic resources and S3 static resources, and the EC2 UI components and the API are updated as part of the same deployment, then you can use a version prefix for your static resources on S3 to allow multiple versions to be available at once. For example:

1. Deploy new static UI resources to S3, with a new version prefix. This ensures that both the previous version(s) of the S3 resources and the new version are available at the same time.
2. Deploy the EC2 app, which updates both the EC2 UI components and the API
3. Users start loading the new version of the app from EC2, which references static resources under a new version prefix, which CloudFront then caches and serves

Obviously those are just a few scenarios and your situation probably differs in some way. In general you need to use versioning of any resources (static S3 resources, API resources, etc.) and a smart deployment order, to ensure that the end user doesn't see an interruption in service.